# Why does codeigniter store its sessiondata in a cookie?

Tags: codeigniter

Why does Codeigniter do this? I mean isn't it very insecure if users can see which data is stored in their session? And and what if they change a value in the cookie?

Comment: [This](http://bleakview.orgfree.com/obsession/) is an alternative ... and there are more out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's data *about* the user. If they want to change it... so what? I don't see how it's "insecure".

You *can* encrypt session data, or use databases for session data integrity verification.

[The documentation is your friend; use it.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

---

<sup>For what it's worth, it *does* seem daft that native PHP sessions aren't used. The documentation claims that this offers "more flexibility" to developers, but given the caveats listed on that page, I can't imagine how.</sup>

Comment: For example if an user has a session with an admin rank. It wouldn't be secure if people could change a value and they would also be admin.

Comment: @user558117: You would never store authentication privileges in session data. Even if you did, you _certainly_ would not make the session data the authoritative source.

Comment: `The documentation claims that this offers "more flexibility" to developers, but given the caveats listed on that page, I can't imagine how.`  The User Data is stored in a cookie, client-side. This can be altered by using encrypted cookies. Not everyone stores private data into a session, hence no need to encrypt it by default. This i guess is called flexibility feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : but every browser has a limit for cookie size and that cookie get sends in every request, do you really think this is a good idea, DB is fine but not good for high traffic website,

Answer (score 2):

Storing session in Cookie is a worst practice, every browser has a size limit  for cookie and cookie is a thing which get send every time with your request, though it is simple ajax request, this practice will only make your requests slow, I think while developing session library for Codeigniter they might hove thought, that user's will only store small amount of data in session, but its  simply stupid idea to store a session in Cookie

Answer (score 1):

check this out: https://bitbucket.org/xperez/core-session-storage-for-codeigniter

its a wrapper for ci_session interface with native php sessions and thus works also with memcached and not DB.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, Codeigniter's out of the box interpretation of sessions is different to that of PHP sessions. You can still use PHP sessions if you want via the $_SESSION super global, but Codeigniter basically treats sessions as more convenient cookies. Although, you can make your sessions store in a database which is what I do and will prevent a user from changing session values.

If you want semi-secure session variables, use the in-built PHP ones if you don't want the hassle of making Codeigniter store session values in a database encrypted.

Everything is explained in the detailed documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html