# Why is CodeIgniter storing IP address, user agent and last activity in cookie?

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies

I've read
[Why does codeigniter store its sessiondata in a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833830/why-does-codeigniter-store-its-sessiondata-in-a-cookie)

and I still don't really understand why does Codeigniter need to store the IP, user agent and last activity in the session cookie. Isn't the session id the only variable it should store in the cookie. My web application stores the session data in the database - so why is this data still stored in the cookie. Moreover, shouldn't Codeigniter get the IP and user agent from the $_SERVER var?

Can somebody clarify this? I've read also CI's documentation over Sessions http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html and it says that also my custom session data would be saved in the cookie, but it seems also that this is not the case. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I think about is security. If someone steal your cookie and try to login as yourself, there are some chances that he doesn't have the same IP and User-Agent. In this case, CodeIgniter would detect a possible intrusion and will end the session.

About session data in cookie, it depends what you told CodeIgniter about where/how to store it. It can be in Database, or in cookie under an encrypted form, or just in plain text (serialized, though) in the cookie.

Comment: Yes, but the attacker might just alter the cookie then? He cannot forge his own IP address which is stored in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'] but he can do so in the cookie... I don't see how storing the IP in the cookie could bring more security, it's actually quite the opposite? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, that's just something the attacker would maybe forget. Actually, it makes more sense when this kind of data is out of the attacker scope (for instance: in database). In this case, the attacker doesn't even know what IP/UserAgent is stored and can't reproduce it. As I said, I'm just guessing :)