# How do I disable a constructor for only a particular method in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I have more than 30 methods in this User Controller.I don't want to create another controller just for this single method.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
            $error['error'][] = "Please LogIn";
            echo json_encode($error);
            exit;
        }
    }


    public function index(){
    }

    public function get_public_pages(){

    }


}
```

I don't want the constructor function to run when accessing get_public_pages method.How can I do it?

Comment: Use codeigniter session instead of $_SESSION['userid']

Comment: Thanks but that is not the problem here! :)

Comment: you can try vinod's answer but **constructor** will always initialize else you can try moving your code in a `pre-controller hook` and check, but that would be an overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $method = $this->router->fetch_method();  

  if(empty($method ) && $method != 'get_public_pages'){
    if(empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
        $error['error'][] = "Please LogIn";
        echo json_encode($error);
        exit;
    }
 }  
}
```

Comment: I just want to disable section for this get_public_pages method.
I'm not using codeigniter sessions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833830/why-does-codeigniter-store-its-sessiondata-in-a-cookie

Comment: Nice solution, Worked well for me.